# Post meta query not having desired outcome

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to do a query on an acf boolean field to get '**pinned_post**' (acf field) go to the top of the results then the rest of the posts ordered my the date if they are not a **pinned_post**

The code below makes the pinned post appear at the very bottom of the paginated results, and it also makes a post that has been previously pinned, but not any more appear next to it.

It's problematic working with acf boolean fields, because i cannot simply do something like:

```
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'key' => 'pinned_post',
        'value' => 1
    )
    );

    $query->set('orderby', array(
        'meta_value' => 'DESC', // Pinned posts come first
        'date' => 'DESC', // Then order by date
    ));
```

So if there's a way to force the acf field to return false when empty, that might also be a solution

I'm also not sure whether or not there's already something interfering with the pre_get_posts hook

I have looked at this answer; [Sort meta_query with boolean custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56714587/sort-meta-query-with-boolean-custom-field)

but it does a similar thing, whereby if there has been a field already checked previously, then it also is put to the front of the results, behind any other pinned posts

```
function meta_pinned_posts($query) {
    if (!is_main_site() || is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || !(is_archive() || is_home())) {
        return;
    }

    // Set up meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'pinned_post' => array(
            'key' => 'pinned_post',
            'value' => '1', // Pinned posts
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        'non_pinned_post' => array(
            'key' => 'pinned_post',
            'value' => '0', // Non-pinned posts
            'compare' => '=',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        ),
        'null_pinned_post' => array(
            'key' => 'pinned_post',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // Posts with no 'pinned_post' field
        ),
    ));

    // Set sorting
    $query->set('orderby', array(
        'pinned_post' => 'DESC', // Pinned posts come first
        'date' => 'DESC', // Then order by date
    ));

    $query->set('order', 'DESC');
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'meta_pinned_posts');
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off doing two queries, one when field `pinned_post` is `1` (number, not string), and one when  `pinned_post` is `0`, and then merge the resulting posts arrays via PHP's `array_merge()` similar to this [SE post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55519/can-i-merge-2-new-wp-queryvariable-s)

Comment: You should not try to limit what the `pinned_post` field _contains_ in your query to begin with here - you do not want to use this as a _selection_ criterion, but only as a _sorting_ criterion. And for that, you only need `meta_key` to be present in your query, but _not_ a comparison to any value.